# What's the reason for the the Lagonda Series II dashboard to use a mixture of metric and imperial?

Tags: history

The title says it all. I'm puzzled if there is a technical (Hardware/Software) reason behind the weird mixture of metric (*Celsius* for temperature) and non metric (like *psi* for pressure) in the Aston Martin Lagonda Series II (and later) dashboard.

This is especially noteworthy as distance and speed measurement can be adjusted between metric and imperial, while others can't. Also, with the Series III vector screens labelling wasn't an issue anymore, but despite the throughout redesign, the limitations where kept.

[image]
(Series III dashboard. Note not only the screens but also the sensor button field)

---

Since assumptions did come up, about it 'just' being some display, The whole car electronics are computer controlled. It's not like some (later) manufacturers adding superfluous systems complementing the workings, here everything runs thru the system (much like today). Every switch and every light. The only non-computer device was an additional mechanical odometer beside the engine for legal reasons.

The system itself being a discrete [National Semiconductor PACE](https://archive.org/details/bitsavers_nationaldaet_782440), an early 16 bit system

Comment: @StephenKitt Mind to explain why? It's about an application running on a way classic IMP-16 system using not one but 3 vector CRT. Can it get more classic?

Comment: I didn’t know that the dashboard was a fully modifiable computer display — I found that out in the mean time, which is why I deleted my comment. (Incidentally I would recommend mentioning that in the question.)

Comment: This seems very off-topic to me.  Whatever limitations or design choices might have led to mixing metric and non-metric units, it probably wasn't the fact that these were being displayed using a computer-driven CRT.  This is kind of like asking why ATMs don't allow me to withdraw more than a certain amount each day.  The fact that ATMs have computers in them doesn't automatically make this a computing question.

Comment: @KenGober Right, or even more like "Why can't I enter the Dollar-value for my desired withdrawal at this ATM in China..."

Comment: @KenGober Since it's not about a "finacial product", but real world physics, it may not be as arbitary as you assume. Also, you might want to take a look at the system we're talking about. A full figured 16 bit computer of the 1970s. So the assumption that there may be some computer/hardware related issues isn't as far fetched as you try to imply - unless you got some detailed information, in which case it would be nice to share them :)

Comment: http://66.media.tumblr.com/d81147ddd7c2b394074c3a56749b2b59/tumblr_nnjd4fjT9v1tkbdg7o3_1280.jpg in case anybody wants the visual evidence of retro computing at play.

Comment: @Tommy It's incredible beautiful, isn't it?

Comment: The mix of units is still present in current cars — for example the tyre pressure indicator often still shows psi, and of course in the UK cars show mph since that’s what is used for speed limits; but °C is generally used for temperature.

Answer (score 14):

This does not seem to about computer systems (retro or otherwise) but cultural assimilation of different standardised measurement systems.

To me, as a UK based user of [halo cars](https://www.popularmechanics.com/cars/a8075/what-good-is-a-halo-car-anyway-12206624/) it seems clear. In the UK we just use a mish-mash of units. I buy petrol in litres and measure distance in Miles. In fact it annoys me that my trip computer does not give me Miles/Litre and insists on Miles/Gallon or Km/Litre. Temperature is in Celsius and so on ...

All pressure gauges show PSI at the garage not Pascals. I weight in Kg but measure in inches.

Aston-Martin Lagonda is a UK based British marque. This would be normal for them then and now.

Nothing strange in my mind. Nothing retro, nothing computing.

Comment: This passes the sniff test for me as another British person (albeit one natively in centimetres), but I have no independent idea of whatever the usual measure of tyre pressure is now since I've never owned a car in the UK, let alone what it was in the '70s, and there's a whole morass of class and generational differences that I daren't comment on.

Comment: :)) I like that assesment - except, I got the feeling this is more about todays Britain than mid 1970s - a time when people where still active moanng about the loss of duodecimal coinageand not using kg or Celsius at all. Further, the Lagonda is a special Brit product, as at that time it was basicly taken over by a bunch of wealthy Americans (US and Canada), including a head figure at NSC - which in turn was the head behind using a full figured 16 bit system. (In addition, I usually dislike halo cars, my Lagonda is the exception to prove the rule :))

Comment: @Raffzahn Us Brits have always used Celsius, really. It's weird Americans who use a scale based on... armpit temperatures? I think? Celsius is part of our "imperial".

Comment: My ~70-year-old parents definitely use centigrade, even as they measure their own weights in stone and talk about pints of milk.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I remember the UK weather being in °F: early 70s, I think.

Comment: Right... I'm still annoyed that I can't get a sat nav that'll give me short distances in metres but long distances in miles, despite the fact that that's just the way a typical British person who grew up in the 80s tends to think.  Because we grew up in a country that had just started to transition from imperial to metric measurements, and got a very odd mixture of the two. :)

Comment: @scruss - I remember TV weather having both units on screen but only reading out the celsius, which must have been early 80s (as my memories of the 70s are *very* hazy).

Comment: Wait until you learn about links, chains and roods :-)

Comment: @scruss It often tends to be °F when it's warm ([_90F heatwave to hit Britain_](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/weather/5652782/90F-heatwave-to-hit-Britain-as-Met-Office-issues-health-alert.html)) and °C when it's cold ([_Winter hits Britain as temperatures plummet to -5C_](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/home-news/uk-weather-latest-frost-temperature-cold-winter-season-nationwide-minus-celcius-ice-a8026766.html))

Comment: In the 1970s, we were already fully metric in science lessons but the world outside was fully imperial including Fahrenheit for temperatures.  It is still a mess today, fruit juice in litres but milk in pints.  The tyre pressure chart in the door frame of my BMW is bar only but my cheap pressure gauge is PSI only, luckily my mental arithmetic is good.

Comment: @TripeHoundtri I think that it is totally bonkers but I see that as well.  I even have one friend who defends the mad habit.